# Create Array of JsonObject in R

Tags: r, rjava

I am able to create a json object from  list in R using rJson .

I used

```
config <- list([Portname="PORT.H.2",MktValue="8000000",WtScheme="Closed"])
json <- toJSON(config)
```

How can I pass array of keyvalue pair to my R function and then convert it to jsonArray in R

I would like to pass

```
  {[Portname="PORT.H.1",MktValue="1000000",WtScheme="Variable], [Portname="PORT.H.2",MktValue="8000000",WtScheme="Closed"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(rjson)
config <- list(Portname="PORT.H.1",MktValue="1000000",WtScheme="Variable")
config2 <- list(Portname="PORT.H.2",MktValue="8000000",WtScheme="Closed")
json <- toJSON(list(config,config2)) 
cat(json)
#[{"Portname":"PORT.H.1","MktValue":"1000000","WtScheme":"Variable"},{"Portname":"PORT.H.2","MktValue":"8000000","WtScheme":"Closed"}]>
```